# on which place does spring data jdbc evaluate that a record is new?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Imagine you have a plain entity with a key property, annotated with @Id. You want to create your own ids, so you created a JdbcConfig with a typical `BeforeConvertCallback` setting an UUID.

Now you create somewhere an instance and instead of null you set an empty String on this id. If you now save this entity, spring data jdbc assumes this entity as an old one and tries to update this entity.

So, where do I have to check that ids are really null and not filled with some empty Strings?

I already changed the `BeforeConvertCallback` with the id generation, but this doesn't help.

```
    @Bean
    BeforeConvertCallback<AnEntity> beforeSaveCallback() {
        return (entity) -> {
            if (entity.getId() == null || entity.getId().isEmpty()) {
                log.info("we have null or empty id");
                entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            return entity;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no earlier event or callback to use for this.

Instead of putting an empty space in the id just make it a proper `null` value.

Of course, you may always implement [`Persistable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) to control yourself, what is and what isn't considered a *new* entity.